# Raster reprojection code not working in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I swear this used to work. I don't get any errors which is the confusing part- it just regurgitates the same layer in its original projection (in this case epsg 32630).

Version of Q is 3.10 A corunya.

```
raster = "raster.tif" #replace with a tif of your own not in 27700
crs = 27700 #british national grid

#reproj raster layer
processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", 
{'INPUT': path + raster,
'SOURCE_CRS':None,
'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("'" + 'EPSG:' + "'" + str(crs) + "'"),
'RESAMPLING':0,
'NODATA':None,
'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,
'OPTIONS':'',
'DATA_TYPE':0,
'TARGET_EXTENT':None,
'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,
'MULTITHREADING':False,
'EXTRA':'',
'OUTPUT':path + raster})
rasterMap = iface.addRasterLayer(path + raster, "raster")
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I don't think it can do a reprojection with the SOURCE_CRS set to None shouldn't it be EPSG:32630?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that. Hmmmm..

Let's see what the target CRS is...

```
>>> QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("'" + 'EPSG:' + "'" + str(crs) + "'")
<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: invalid>
```

Invalid? Hmmm what's that string turning out to be?

```
>>> "'" + 'EPSG:' + "'" + str(crs) + "'"
"'EPSG:'27700'"
```

There's a lot of odd quote marks in there. Let's simplify:

```
>>> QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:" + str(crs))
<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:27700>
```

That works for me in the processing call!

Not sure if your format with all the quotes should ever have worked, or maybe something has cleaned up the processing of strings to `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` to be a bit more strict.

Comment: `f"EPSG: {crs}"` would be the nice modern Python variant with less surprises :)

Comment: Neither of these worked for me. Feel like I'm going mad....

Comment: Are you getting "invalid" for literally `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:27700")`? It seems *very* fussy, and the extra space introduced by @bugmenot123 comment is enough to break it.

Comment: Oops, sorry. `f"EPSG:{code}"`.